# unity ARCore Rendering issue in orientation

Tags: unity-game-engine, orientation, arcore

There is a rendering issue in ARCore. I need a landscape oriented scene in ARCore. I worked on an example scene in ARCore sdk. I changed the orientation to landscape left. I just put a game object 1m in front the camera. When I run the project everything works fine.

But what my problem is, at first the game object renders in portrait mode, then it changes its orientation to landscape mode. Which means there is a flickering on game object in orientation when starting. I think this happens from ARCore itself. That is not good to go.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code?